# how can i change text "cancel" in time picker to anther text in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

```
  class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
            val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year: Int = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month: Int = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day: Int = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            return DatePickerDialog(getActivity()!!, this, year, month, day)
        }

        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
            val tv: TextView = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.txt_date_picker) as TextView
            tv.setText("$day - $month - $year")
        }

        override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
            Toast.makeText(activity,"date picker Canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            super.onCancel(dialog)

        }
    }
```

---

**Edit:** All code after trying answer:

```
class TimePickerFragment: DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
    private lateinit var calendar:Calendar

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance()


        val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)


        return TimePickerDialog(
            activity, // Context
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth, // Theme
            this, // TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
            hour, // Hour of day
            minute, // Minute
            false // Is 24 hour view
        )//.apply {
          //  getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setText(R.string.myCancelString)
       // }


    }


    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        // Do something with the returned time
        val tv:TextView = activity.findViewById(R.id.end) as TextView
      //  tv.text = "${getHourAMPM(hourOfDay)}:$minute ${getAMPM(hourOfDay)}"
        tv.text = "$hourOfDay:$minute "
    }

}
```

Comment: From [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#inherited-methods) it looks like buttons inherit a "setText" method from class android.widget.TextView.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the button and change its text after the dialog is created, which happens in `onStart()`:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    (dialog as? DatePickerDialog)
        ?.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        ?.setText(R.string.myCancelString)
}
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(int)' on a null object reference

i try it but this error happened

Comment: not worked code please help me in anther way  (dialog) doesn't known for android

Comment: I tested it and it works fine for me. Would have to see your complete code to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: how can i send it to you ??

Comment: Edit your question to add it.

Comment: Your new code doesn't have my code added above. You commented out my obsolete code but didn't add the fixed code.

Comment: the ather code i put it in main exactly in (on start )but the android studio didn''t understand word dialog

Comment: and i put (dialog)as variable but the cancel button on the in the time picker still named **cancel :(

Comment: My code above goes in the DialogFragment, not in the Activity.

Comment: Like I said before, I can’t help if you don’t show your actual code that is not working.

Comment: can you give me a reference or something talk about this thing i put my code and yours on it i don't know what is the problem :(

Comment: i found the solution her but it was in java and i couldn't convert it into kotlin

Comment: I don't have any references. If you post your complete activity and fragment code I can probably tell you what's wrong.